# Bootstrap Tab in Angular Js not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating an angular js Application. which has a side bar navigation sustem. when I click on the sidebar item, then it has to show contents under that item in the content section,I am using bootstrap
See the code I've written

**HTML**

```
 <div class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in supplyItem">
                    <a class="span" href="#{{item.header}}">{{item.header}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="content-part">

              <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" ng-repeat="item in supplyItem" id="{{item.header}}">
                {{item.desc}}                
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.
    when('/home',{
        templateUrl : 'partials/home_page.aspx',
        controller:'HomePageController',
    }).
    when('/supplies',{
        templateUrl : 'partials/supplies.aspx',
        controller:'MyController',
    }).

    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });


}]);

    appController.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.supplyItem = [
        {
            "header": "header1",
            "desc": "Descipriotn 1"
        },
        {

            "header": "header2",
            "desc": "Descipriotn 2"

        }
        ];

        $('.sidebar a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
                $(this).tab('show');
            });

            $(function () {
                $('.sidebar a:last').tab('show');
            });
    } ]);
```

but when I click on sidebar nav item it goes to the home page as i mentioned in the *routeProvider.otherwise()*

what is the error and how do I solve this ? any one help me please

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have the ids of your tap-pane divs different:

id="item.header" should be id="{{item.header}}"

Comment: ohh, thats a question mistake, actually it is like you said in my original code, I've edited code

Answer (score 1):

Also I noticed that in you JS you have:

> $scope.supplyItem = [
>           {
>               "header": "header1",
>               "desc": "Descipriotn 1"
>           },
>           {
>               "header": "header1",
>               "desc": "Descipriotn 2"
>           }
>           ];

And I think that the "header" values should be different in order for the bootstrap plugin to discriminate between the different divs.

Comment: Ok, in that case, the header attribute is assigned to the a href att and I think that they should be /home and /supplies. I this another typo? ;)

Comment: i didnt get that, what you mean ?

Comment: Ohh I got it wrong. Can you try to debug your sidebar click listener with a console.log or somethign to see if it gets called? Because I think that you are using the $ selector and it is not getting any values because AngularJS has not yet put the items in the DOM.

Comment: I have added an alert beofre, but it is not taking , that is the event is not working

Comment: Well, that's what I was thinking. I think you should use ng-click on the tab divs pointing to your listener. That way you ensure that it's angular-safe

Comment: can you explain little bit more with help of code ?

Comment: ' <a class="span" href="#{{item.header}}" ng-click='func'>{{item.header}}</a>'

Comment: and then in the controller:
$scope.func = function() { you listener code }

See this for more examples: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_events.asp

Comment: hei I've tried this method too, but it is also not working see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270797/ng-click-event-not-works-for-link-in-angular-js