# ng-click event not works for link in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Hi in my angular application, I am using routeProvider for routing partials,
and in one page i have a set of links i am using ng-href for providing link. and I have a ng-click event for the link. but when I click on the link the page goes to the otherWise section of routeProvider and loads the page I have defined there.

see the code

**HTML**

```
           <li ng-repeat="item in supplyItem">
                <a class="span" ng-click="showDetails()" ng-href="#{{item.header}}">
                    {{item.header}}
                </a>
            </li>
```

**App.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[
    'ngRoute',
    'appController'
    ]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.
    when('/home',{
        templateUrl : 'partials/home_page.aspx',
        controller:'HomePageController',
    }).
    when('/supplies',{
        templateUrl : 'partials/supplies.aspx',
        controller:'SupplyController',
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });


}]);
```

**controller.js**

```
appController.controller('SupplyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.firstITem = "Acrylics";
    $scope.showDetails = function() {
        alert("clicked");

    }


 $scope.supplyItem = [
    {
        "header": "Acrylics",
        "Acrylics": [
                "Custom Tray Material",
                "Reline Materials",
                "Reline Materials-Hard",
                "Reline Materials-Soft",
                "Repair Acrylics",
                "Resin & Pattern Materials",
                "Temporary Crown and Bridge Material",
                "Tissue Conditioner",
                ]
    }
];


} ]);
```

what is the error ? how can I solve this

Comment: Is your issue that the ng-click does not work?

Comment: @PSL yes it is not calling the function

Comment: How would you be able to if the function is not attached to scope.? `$scope.showDetails = ...`

Comment: @PSL I have tried attaching function with scope var, but it is not still working

Comment: @PSL not working means when I click on the link it is going to the home_page.aspx instead of calling thshowDetails() method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70016/discussion-between-cybro-and-psl).

Comment: here is js fiddle link that shows that ur ng-click is working. http://jsfiddle.net/s1covosh/

Comment: @chandings I think the problem is not with ng-click event, the problem is with routeProvider, the routeProviders triggers action before triggering the click event, that is the issue

Comment: try using this cdn link for angular-route. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/<version>/angular-route.js

Answer (score 1):

Your controller should contains your function as an field of the `$scope`, so it looks like this:

```
$scope.firstITem = "Acrylics";
$scope.showDetails = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("clicked");
}
```

Also I think you shouldn't use `ng-href`, because click overrides your `href`

Comment: tried this method by removing ng-href but still the same

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.showDetails = function() {
    enter code here
}
```

loose the ng-href, if you want the link to activate after the click event.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in supplyItem">
    <a class="span" ng-click="showDetails(item)">
        {{item.header}}
    </a>
</li>

$scope.showDetails = function(item) {

    alert();
    window.location.href = "#' + item.header;
}
```

Comment: this is working, means the alert is showing , but after that it goes to the home page again, I have passed event , and prevented Default action , but still the same